git warned about overwriting one file's local changes before switching branch but lost other files' local changes too
I had been working on a certain branch and I decided that some of the files should go to a new branch instead. So I committed the files that needed to go into this branch, and with uncommitted changes in the other files, I attempted to checkout master. git warned that the local changes in a particular file would be overwritten. As that was a file with a a single line change that I could retype again, I chose the force checkout option. But after the branch checkout I find that the other files with local changes have vanished without a trace. Why did this happen?

Because you overwrote the file. Consider committing or stashing the changes before switching branches

@evolutionxbox the OP committed, that's why.

So... sure, because you committed, those changes are not there when you switch. You can cherry-pick that commit from where you were working to be able to apply it on the current branch. The other approach you can easily use in these cases is stashing as @evolutionxbox explained.

@eftshift0 thanks. I thought the OP wondered why their uncommitted changes got overwritten

exactly. Still unanswered.

@WalkingCorpse may you clarify what you meant?

The 'will be overwritten' warning was shown for a single file. I had changes in several files. I assumed they won't be overwritten when the branch checkout happens but they got overwritten.

@WalkingCorpse When you switch branches, Git tries to update your working directory to match the files in the target branch. If you have uncommitted changes in file A that also exist in branch two, Git warns you because switching branches would overwrite your local changes. Git may also overwrite committed files without warning. Say if file A in branch one and file A in branch two have different contents.
